# Convert HTML data into Text format

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium Web Driver to extract data points from LinkedIn profiles. In this example I want to extract each skill from the skills section but the data is extracted as HTML format.

When trying to convert the HTML code to text I get the attached error message.

```
from parsel import Selector  
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys  
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/davidcraven/Downloads/chromedriver')

# get profile URL
driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com/AnyProfileURL')

# assigning the source code for the web page to variable sel
sel = Selector(text=driver.page_source)

# get skills
skills = sel.xpath('//*[starts-with(@class, "skills searchable has-several ")]').extract()

newtext = BeautifulSoup(skills, "lxml").text
```

[image]

Comment: Is skills not a list in this case (using extract) rather than a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to select an element first:

```py
driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com/AnyProfileURL')
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")
elem = soup.select_one('.skills.searchable.has-several')
if elem:
    txt = elem.text
```

Comment: Thanks man, although the output comes like this not separated by a comma. How could I separate each different skill?

Output: 
'Event PlanningAdvertisingCRMLeadershipAccount ManagementSportsSalesTicket SalesBusiness DevelopmentEvent ManagementPublic SpeakingCustomer Relationship Management (CRM)Customer ServiceMarketingSports MarketingContract NegotiationNew Business DevelopmentSalesforce.comSponsorshipSellingEmail Marketing'

Comment: @dcraven you're going to have add another select on elem and select each element that contains a skill then read each one and add them to a list